# git cross cloning, how to make one follow the other?

Tags: git, github

I decided to backup my directory with git, so I did `git init` and `git add` and `git commit` and all. Now I can manage the version on my hard disk. I was afraid I could lose those directory so I cloned it from another location (physically difference disk) and whenever I git commit from the first repo (and original), I pulled it from the second directory.

This morning, I deleted all the files in the original directory and I was relieved I have another repo in the second directory. So I cloned the second directory to the first directory location. and I realize the first directory has the second directory as the origin, and the second directory has the first directory as the origin. Before this morning's accident, when I pull or checkout in the first directory, it was referenced to itself, but now it is the second directory as the origin. and the second directory has the first directory as the origin. They are now cross gitting!

I'm worried I may screw things up in this configuration (of course I can copy whole directory to a third directory for safety). How can I make the first directory as the real origin and make second directory follow the first directory as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you had a `repo A` on one disk, which you cloned as `repo B` on disk2. So, the origin for `repo B` is right now `repo A`, and `repo A` does not have any origin.

Afterwards, you deleted `repo A`, and then cloned it back from `repo B`. So now, `repo A` also has a origin set to `repo B`.

To resolve this, you just need to remove the remote from `repo A` using the following:

```
cd repo_A
git remote remove origin
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I peeked into .git/cofig of repo A. it has only [core] section. but in repo B, it has [remote "origin"] and [branch "master"] section after [core] section. I reckon this `git remote remove origin` is deleting those origin and master secion from the .git/config of repo A (so that it becomes independent again).

Comment: @ChanKim Yes, you are spot on. Another way to have done this would have been exactly that - remove the entries from your `.git/config` for `[remote "origin"]`

Comment: BTH, looks like the exact command seems to be `git remote rm origin`.